# How does passing a lambda using std::ref in an algorithm work in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, reference

I understand that when you pass a variable by reference, the function receives a reference to the original variable, allowing it to modify the variable's value directly. However, I'm curious about how this concept applies to callable objects like lambda functions? which part of the code gets modified? And does this apply to other callable objects, like functors?

Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
int main()
{

    
    std::array<int, 5> data{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    auto func = [sum = 0](int value) mutable -> int
    {
        sum += value;
        return sum;
    };

    std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ref(func));
    std::cout << func(3) << '\n';

}
```

Comment: I'm about to let you in on a deeply held secret that's only known to a select few C++ gurus: a lambda is just an anonymous class with an `operator()` overload. Captured parameters are class members. The constructor initializes them from the capture expression. Without a `mutable` qualifier they are `const` class members, otherwise they're non-const. The lambda itself is the `operator()` overload. The end result is an object. No different than any other object, as far as objects in C++ go. Your `std::ref` is just a `std::ref` of that object.

Comment: This is bad code. If it is used to teach you then it throws at you things which are not very important for beginner and are considered as bad practice (mutable lambda which is used multiple times). This example will make harder for you understand what lambda actually does. Good code would use `std::accumulate` .

Comment: @SamVarshavchik WoW! you're awesome!  couldn't be more clear. Thank you so much! you should post this comment as an answer.

Comment: @MarekR yes. it is for learning purposes as the usage of std::ref. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: i just have a question: 
I read how std::reference_wrapper<T>::operator() works:  it is invoking operator() on the original lambda via the reference . does it mean "using the std::reference_wrapper's overloaded operator() to forward the call to the original lambda that it holds a reference to rather than the copy". is that what reference to function call means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas are just shorthand for classes with an overloaded `operator()`.

That is, this:

```
auto func = [sum = 0](int value) mutable -> int
{
    sum += value;
    return sum;
}
```

is just shorthand for something like this:

```
class AnonymousLambdaClass
{
private:
    int sum;

public:
    AnonymousLambdaClass() : sum(0) {}

    auto operator()(int value) -> int
    {
        sum += value;
        return sum;
    }
};
auto func = AnonymousLambdaClass();
```

Objects in the lambda's capture list are class members and the body of the lambda is an overloaded `operator()`.

---

`std::ref` is just a helper function that returns a `std::reference_wrapper<T>`.  `std::reference_wrapper` is a pretty simple class template that looks something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class reference_wrapper
{
private:
    T* ref_;

public:
    reference_wrapper(T& r) : ref_(&r) {}

    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const
    {
        return (*ref_)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    T& get() const { return *ref_; }
    operator T&() const { return *ref_; }
};
```

---

Putting these together, `std::ref(func)` returns a `std::reference_wrapper<AnonymousLambdaClass>` that holds a pointer to `func`.  When you call the resulting object you're calling the `reference_wrapper`'s overloaded `operator()`, which in turn passes its arguments through to the `operator()` of the underlying `AnonymousLambdaClass` object which contains the body of the lambda that you wrote.

Comment: Absolutely informative and fantastic answer!  Thank you so much. That's exactly what I wanted to know: what is happening under the hood.  I Love C++.

Comment: When a lambda function is passed by value to std::for_each, the function operates on a separate copy of the lambda for each element it processes, but does this copying process include all those the operator() and std::forwarding etc of the lambda?

Comment: @Sami `std::for_each` does not make a copy for each iteration; it only copies the lambda once (when it's passed by-value).  Besides that it's just like copying any other object of a class type.  Member functions (such as the `operator()` overload of the lambda) only exist once and get passed a hidden `this` argument that is a pointer to the object they were called on.

Comment: I'm trying to deepen my understanding of C++ and its nuances. I realize that practice is essential to learning any language, but I'm wondering what specific strategies or resources you'd recommend for learning about the more subtle aspects of C++. In particular, do you think studying the examples on cppreference.com would be a good approach? Are there other resources or techniques you'd suggest ?I want to understand it like they way you all here answers questions.